# How to convert a Nonetype object into string or DataFrame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've some issues with 'NoneType' object in my program (written on pandas).
This is my code:

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession
from pyairvisual import Client
import pandas as pd

place = ['Brussels','Steenokkerzeel','Antwerpen','Aarschot','Amsterdam','London']
state1 = ['Brussels Capital','Flanders','Flanders','Flanders','North Holland','England']

n = 2
async def main() -> None:
    """Create the aiohttp session and run the example."""
    async with ClientSession() as websession:
        client = Client('fWw2GEy25CqmFQMaA', websession)

        data = await client.data.city(
        city = place[n], state = state1[n], country = 'Belgium')
        print(data)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

And I tried this:

```
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main()).to_string()
```

But the result was:

```
{'city': 'Antwerpen', 'state': 'Flanders', 'country': 'Belgium', 'location': 
{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [4.34100506499574, 51.1702980406645]}, 
'current': {'weather': {'ts': '2018-10-30T06:00:00.000Z', 'hu': 60, 'ic': 
'09n', 'pr': 986, 'tp': 4, 'wd': 350, 'ws': 1.5}, 'pollution': {'ts': '2018- 
 10-30T07:00:00.000Z', 'aqius': 33, 'mainus': 'p2', 'aqicn': 16, 'maincn': 
 'n2'}}}
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-22-a1764c0a80fe> in <module>()
 ----> 1 asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main()).to_string()

 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_string'
```

I want to get the data between the accolades and set it into a string or DataFrame, but I don't know how to convert the 'NoneType' object to string or DataFrame. Do somebody else know the solution?

Thank you.

Comment: df.fillna('',inplace=True)

Comment: @RudolfMorkovskyi can you explain more about it?

Comment: You can fill empty cells (or None cells) as you need via `fillna` function https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

Comment: Maybe you can modify your problem to be able to reproduce it without installing those libraries

Comment: How is `fillna()` at all relevant to this question?  @RudolfMorkovskyi

Answer (score 1):

You are currently returning `None` from your coroutine `main()`, as you indicate via type hinting.  (And because the return value of `print()` is `None`).

`loop.run_until_complete()` will transmit the return value of `main()`, which is `None`, and you're attempting to call `None.to_string()` as a result.

You need to `return` an object from `main()`.  It's up to you what that is:

```
async def main() -> None:
    async with ClientSession() as websession:
        client = Client('fWw2GEy25CqmFQMaA', websession)
        data = await client.data.city(
            city=place[n], state=state1[n], country='Belgium')
    return data
```

If you want a string, instead of `.to_string()`, use `json.dumps()` on the result of the asyncio call.  If you want a DataFrame, check out the Pandas documentation on how to instantiate a DataFrame from a Python dictionary.